# VMWare VM - Virtual Cable Unplugged

Tags: networking, macos, virtual-machine, internet-connection, vmware-fusion

#### Introduction

I'm running VMware Fusion v11.5.1 on a macOS 10 host. I'm attempting to reach the Internet from inside a virtual machine.

#### What I've done so far

I was trying to reach the Internet from inside a CentOS 7 VM. The network adapter is in NAT mode. Here's a picture of my network settings:

[image: network settings]

As you can see, the virtual ethernet cable is unplugged and greyed out.

I started up a Windows 10 VM and a similar thing happened.

I reconnected the network adapter and reinstalled VMware Fusion, and the same thing continued happening.

#### Question

How can I reach the Internet from within a virtual machine managed by VMware Fusion 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I powered off my VM, restarted my Mac, and started the VM up again and that was enough to get my VM connected again.

Answer (score 0):

For me this fixed the problem:
Go to VMware's settings > network adapter > network connection: change it from "NAT" to "Bridged".

My host machine is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Check the VM Network setting, some time there might be cable connected box may be unchecked due this cable unplugged you will see in vm machine.